# Leader Key Shortcuts in Spacemacs

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

In the [Spacemacs Documentation](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/#dotfile-spacemacs), creating the `.spacemacs` dotfile is accomplished with the following command:

```
<SPC> : dotspacemacs/install RET
```

I parse this as being the following string (note the preceding space):

```
 : dotspacemacs/install
```

followed by me hitting the enter key.

When I open up emacs and type the first space, nothing appears to happen and my computer makes a sound I typically hear with invalid input. I have also tried the following:

1. `: dotspacemacs/install` (no preceding space). This gives me `Unknown command:` `dotspacemacs/install`
2. `M-x` (on my keyboard alt x) followed by both of the previously mentioned commands. These both result in `[no match]`

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I dont know spacemacs. It seems space and colon should be the equivalent of emacs M-x which should place you in the minibuffer at the bottom on the window. Dont type a space after that. I presume you did the git clone into ~/.emacs.d and ran emacs twice for the install process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you see the spacemacs buffer after you started emacs? 
make sure you install the spacemacs correctly or you can copy that file manually :

cp ~/.emacs.d/core/templates/.spacemacs.template ~/.spacemacs

close emacs and reopen to see if works

Answer (score 1):

```
SPC f e d
```

does create / open it after a fresh install.